# get id added through knockout data binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

My html code is:

```
<div data-bind="attr:{'id':id}">
     <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
</div>
```

and js code is:

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = data;
    self.name = data.name;
    self.getId = function () {
        var id = document.getElementById(self.id);
        console.log("id is " + id);
        id.scrollTop = id.scrollHeight;
    }
    self.getId();
}
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(5,"irfan"));
})
```

Now in `getId` function how to get the id? As I have to apply scrollTop function on that Id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood the question properly, and I have no idea how to ask you to clarify. Basically, you have multiple mistakes that make it a bit hard to guess at the initial intent. See if this does what you wanted; if not, please explain what you did want to do (that is different from what I'm doing).

```js
function ViewModel(id, name) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
    self.getId = function () {
        console.log("element is ", document.getElementById(self.id()));
    }
}
var vm = new ViewModel(5,"irfan");
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.getId();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="attr:{'id':id}">
     <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
</div>
```

Specifically:

- `data` in your example is just `5`, so `data.name` is `undefined`
- In order to use them in `data-bind`, `id` and `name` need to be Knockout observables
- If you apply `+` (concatenation) to a string and a HTML element, the element will display as `[object HTMLDivElement]`, which is not very useful
- Finally, the answer to your question - each observable is a function, and needs to be invoked - thus, `self.id` would have been fine if you left `id` as non-observable (but then Knockout can't work); now that it is observable, it needs to be `self.id()`.

EDIT: For autoscrolling to bottom, how about this?

```js
function ViewModel(id, name) {
  var self = this;
  self.stuff = ko.observableArray([]);
}
var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.bindingHandlers.scrollToEnd = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var scroller = element.previousSibling.previousSibling;
    scroller.scrollTop = scroller.scrollHeight;
  }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.scrollToEnd = true;

ko.applyBindings(vm);


setInterval(newDataCometh, 1000);

function newDataCometh() {
  var newData = (Math.random() * 100000 + 10000).toString(36); // just random gibberish
  vm.stuff.push(newData);
}
```

```css
#stuff {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="stuff" data-bind="foreach: stuff">
  <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>
<!-- ko scrollToEnd: stuff --><!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: in console complete html is displayed. But I just want Id as I have to apply `scrollHeight` function on that id

Comment: `id` is a number and does not have `scrollHeight`. The element with that `id` has `scrollHeight` - and that is precisely what was displayed, the element. You can totally do `document.getElementById(self.id()).scrollHeight`. However, this smells of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - it may have been better to ask what your ultimate goal is, given that even the fixed-up snippet is code that I am not sure would be good in the long run.

Comment: In my page I have foreach loop and my goal is when new data is append the page should scroll automatically to that data. I have updated the quesiton

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted. How can I add animation in scrolling?